# What kind of storage class should I choose if I want my variable to have separate copy in every thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using `thread_local` as I want my function, being called from several threads, to have a separate copy of variable `rage` in my code. But If I call that function twice from the same thread my variable becomes shared.

So my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

thread_local static int rage = 1; 
std::mutex cout_mutex;

void increase_rage(const std::string& thread_name)
{
    thread_local int rage = 0; 
    ++rage; // modifying outside a lock is okay; this is a thread-local variable
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_mutex);
    std::cout << "Rage counter for " << thread_name << ": " << rage << '\n';
}

void call_mult (const std::string& thread_name1, const std::string& thread_name2)
{
    increase_rage(thread_name1);
    increase_rage(thread_name2);
}

int main()
{
    std::thread a(increase_rage, "a"), b(increase_rage, "b"), c(call_mult, "c", "d");

    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(cout_mutex);
        std::cout << "Rage counter for main: " << rage << '\n';
    }

    a.join();
    b.join();
    c.join();
}
```

my output is:

```
Rage counter for main: 1
Rage counter for a: 1
Rage counter for c: 1
Rage counter for d: 2
Rage counter for b: 1
```

I want function `call_mult` to also have separate copies of variable `rage` even if function is being called twice in the same thread.

Comment: Why do you have 2 variables named `rage`? This is confusing.

Comment: What you want is local variables. If you want local variables use local variables, remove `thread_local`.

Comment: The requirements here are rather muddled. The last sentence says that each call to `increase_rage` should have a separate copy of `rage`. That's easy: just pass it as an argument. The rest of the stuff, about separate copies per thread, seems to be working correctly, but it doesn't do what the last sentence is asking for.

Comment: @PeteBecker that is correct. Everything else is working the way I want but the last sentence.

Comment: then remove `thread_local` from declaration inside function. it will be local for every call then.

Comment: You're missing the point. The last sentence is simple to do. It doesn't require thread-local stuff at all. What is the reason for using thread-local variables? They're often the result of a design mistake.